# xsp2 server start with error

Tags: mono, xsp2

I using linux

I have installed mono, when I run the command xsp2 get the following error:

> Exception caught during reading the configuration file: 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   xsp2
>
> Listening on address: 127.0.0.1
>
> Root directory: /etc/mono
>
> Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
>
> Hit Return to stop the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in the past. But IIRC the error doesn't happen after the first request. And subsequent requests work fine.

Nevertheless, you should report it as a bug in http://buzilla.xamarin.com/ . Also, have you tested xsp4 instead?